# How to cycle through 3 values in a Rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

Is there a better way to do this:

```
row_bg_color_group = row_bg_color_group == 1 ? 2 : row_bg_color_group == 2 ? 3 : 1
```

Ideally something like

```
row_bg_color_group = (1,2,3).cycle
```

and each time through the larger loop the next value would be used.

Please note that this is executed conditionally as part of varying groups size, e.g.

```
1111
1111
1111
2222
3333
3333
3333
333
```

not just

```
111
222
333
111
222
333
111
222
333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `cycle()` in Rails ([docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle)). So you can do:

```
row_bg_color_group = cycle(1,2,3)
```

If you need to have more than one cycle, you can give them names:

```
row_bg_color_group = cycle(1,2,3, :name => "row_bg_color_group")
```

and then they won't conflict.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the modulo operator:

```
row_bg_color_group = ((row_bg_color_group + 1) % 3) + 1
```

I don't know your situation, but this looks a little cleaner if you can use groups numbered 0 through 2 instead of 1 through 3.

```
row_bg_color_group = (row_bg_color_group + 1) % 3
```

Comment: A useful answer (+1) though I find the cycle method more readable.

Answer (score 2):

```
<% outer_loop_control do %>
  <% row_bg_color_group = cycle(1,2,3)
  <% inner_loop_control do %>
    ... # all uses of row_bg_color_group in the inner loop will be the same
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```